# PclZip extract into new folder if folder already exists

Tags: php, zip, clip

i am using PclZip to extract zip file, my problem is how can i extract the zip file into different folder by creating a new folder if the folder is already exits..

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

```
    $destination_dir = "/foo/bar";
    $new_dir = "/foo/bar2";
    if (is_dir($destination_dir)) {mkdir($new_dir); $destination_dir = $new_dir;}
    $archive = new PclZip($file);
    if ($archive->extract(PCLZIP_OPT_PATH, $destination_dir) == 0) {
        die("Unzip failed. Error : ".$archive->errorInfo(true));
    }
    echo "Successfully extracted files to ".$destination_dir;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $destination_dir = "/foo/bar";

    if (file_exists($destination_dir)) { $destination_dir = "/foo/bar2";  }

    mkdir($destination_dir);

    $archive = new PclZip($file);
    if ($archive->extract(PCLZIP_OPT_PATH, $destination_dir) == 0) {
        die("Unzip failed. Error : ".$archive->errorInfo(true));
    }
    echo "Successfully extracted files to ".$destination_dir;
```